# Stalk of the ramification divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a finite, separable morphism of curves $f: X \to Y$. The ramification divisor $R$ is defined as:
$R=\displaystyle \sum_{P \in X} length(\Omega_{X/Y})_P \cdot P$

My purpose is to prove that $\mathcal{O}_{R}$ is isomorphic to $\Omega_{X/Y}$

Clearly they have the same support and moreover, thanks to proposition IV.2.2 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, we have that $(\Omega_{X/Y})_P \cong \mathcal{O}_{X,P}/(g)$, where g is the unique element in $\mathcal{O}_P$ such that $f^*dt = gdu$, where $dt$ and $du$ are respectively the generators of $\Omega_{Y,Q}$ and $\Omega_{X,P}$. How can I see that $\mathcal{O}_{R,P}$ is isomorphic to $(\Omega_{X/Y})_P$?

I have already found here [Proposition IV.2.3 in Hartshorne](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591629/proposition-iv-2-3-in-hartshorne) that an explaination of this isomorphism is given but it is based on very general facts. It can’t be the only way to see it as in Hartshorne’s Algebraic Geometry it is crearly specified that it comes from proposition IV.2.2 , which involves properties of $\Omega_{X/Y}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $R$ is a divisor, you have a short exact sequence
$$0 \to \mathcal O(-R) \to \mathcal O_X \to \mathcal O_R \to 0.$$
(If you are accustomed to the notation in Hartshorne, then $\mathcal O(-R) = \mathcal L(-R)$.) From this you get
$$\mathcal O_{R,P} = \mathcal O_{X,P} / (\pi^{\ell}),$$
where $\pi$ is a generator of $\mathfrak m_P \subset \mathcal O_{X,P}$, and $\ell$ is the length of $\mathcal O_{R,P}$. Here we use that $X$ is smooth. Now by definition, $\ell = \operatorname{length}(\Omega_{X/Y, P})$, so that also
$$\Omega_{X/Y, P} \cong \mathcal O_{X,P} / (\pi^\ell).$$
In the last step we make use of Hartshorne's Proposition IV.2.1, which tells us that also $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is a quotient of $\mathcal O_X$.

Bonus question: Can you think up two sheaves on $X$ with finite support, which have the same length at each $P \in X$, but are not isomorphic?

Comment: I still miss where does $(\pi^{l})$ come from. From the exact sequence I understood that $\mathcal{O}_{R,P} \cong \mathcal{O}_{X,P}/Im(\alpha_P)$, where with $\alpha$ I'm denoting the map $\mathcal{O(-R)} \to \mathcal{O}_X $. But I'm not able to conclude what you said.

Comment: @Guiseppe As $X$ is a smooth curve, the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,P}$ is a principal ideal domain. So $\mathcal O_{R,P} \cong \mathcal O_{X,P} / (f)$. As $\mathcal O_{X,P}$ is local, $f \in \mathfrak m_{P}$ if $\mathcal O_{R,P} \neq 0$, and so $f = u \cdot \pi^\ell$ for some unit $u \in \mathcal O_{X,P}^\times, \ell \in \mathbb N$. Thus $\mathcal O_{R,P} \cong \mathcal O_{X,P} / (\pi^\ell)$.